# Setting property in a class of the type used in the property of a different class

Tags: c#

Pardon me if it is nave;

but i am trying to set a property in class SomeType;

```
public class SomeType<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public T Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

in another;

```
private class Source
{

    public SomeType<String> value1
    {
        get
        {
            return new SomeType<String>();
        }

    }

}
```

In the Test method what i am trying out is simple;

```
Source source = new Source();
source.value1.Value = "Test";
```

but the Value is never "Test"? Am i missing my concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a new `SomeType<string>` object every time you access the `value1` property, so although you're correctly setting the `Value` property on that object, it means that the next time you access `value1` you're getting an entirely new object.

See if this makes any difference:

```
private SomeType<string> _value1 = new SomeType<string>();
public SomeType<string> value1
{
    get
    {
        return _value1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a new instance of SomeType everytime you **access** the value1 property. When you check that Value is "Test" you are checking that it is "Test" on an entirely new object.

Answer (score 0):

In Source.value1, you are creating a new instance of `SomeType<string>` every time the getter is accessed (in itself not a good coding idiom). The default value of string is null, so that's the value of the Value property, because it was never set to anything else.

In other words. this is expected.

Maybe you could share with us what it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

value1 always returns a new SomeType. This is why the answer is never "Test". The code below should fix your issue:

```
private class Source
{
    public SomeType<String> value1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

source.value1 = new SomeType<string>() { Value = "Test" };
```